# including jquery in rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I need to add a jquery effect . A button that should make the content in the paragraph tag  hide on clicking the button. I tried all possible ways but its not working
my code for the view

```
 <p id = "para1">

  <% javascript_include_tag "tweets" %>
    <%=form_tag({controller: 'tweets', action:'index'},  method: "get") do %>
    <%=label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
    <%=text_field_tag(:text)%>
    <%=label_tag(:show, "Show for:") %>
    <%=text_field_tag(:show) %>
    <%= submit_tag( "GO" ) %>

 </p>

  <button type = "button" onclick= "myfunction()">Try it</button>

<%end %>
```

I have included my jquery code in tweets.js inside app/assets/javascripts folder

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(#para1).hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

But in my final view I am getting the search button but when I click nothing is happening .Its not directing to that page which contains that function and becoming invisible.Please help me

Comment: You should use a tool like firebug to check that jQuery is correctly loaded, and that there is no javascript error; also `javascript_include_tag` would be better in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you have added `form` inside paragraph which is not valid html. try to validate url with http://validator.w3.org/

Along with this, you have a typo.

`$(#para1).hide();` needs to be `$("#para1").hide();`

After fixing typo and replacing `<p id = "para1">` by `<div id="para1">`, it will work.